# Variable capture in Common Lisp macros

Tags: variables, macros, common-lisp

The usual way to avoid inadvertant variable capture in macros seems to involve introducing a layer of indirection via `(gensym)`. For example, Paul Graham in On Lisp(http://www.bookshelf.jp/texi/onlisp/onlisp_10.html#SEC67) Ch 9.6, presents a basic `for` loop as:

```
(defmacro for ((var start stop) &body body)
  (let ((gstop (gensym)))
    `(do ((,var ,start (1+ ,var))
         (,gstop ,stop))
         ((> ,var ,gstop))
       ,@body)))
FOR
```

So then the expansion introduces a `gensym` variable #:G450 for the stop value:

```
(macroexpand '(for (i 1 3) (princ i)))
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((I 1) (#:G450 3))
    (TAGBODY
      (GO #:G452)
     #:G451
      (TAGBODY (PRINC I))
      (PSETQ I (1+ I))
     #:G452
      (UNLESS (> I #:G450) (GO #:G451))
      (RETURN-FROM NIL (PROGN)))))
T
```

But this expansion seems like it should be equivalent to the `loop` macro expansion:

```
(macroexpand '(loop for i from 1 upto 3 do (princ i)))
(BLOCK NIL
  (LET ((I 1))
    (DECLARE (TYPE (AND REAL NUMBER) I))
    (SB-LOOP::LOOP-BODY NIL
                        (NIL NIL (WHEN (> I '3) (GO SB-LOOP::END-LOOP)) NIL)
                        ((PRINC I))
                        (NIL (SB-LOOP::LOOP-REALLY-DESETQ I (1+ I))
                         (WHEN (> I '3) (GO SB-LOOP::END-LOOP)) NIL)
                        NIL)))
T
```

where there are no `gensym` variables.

How does `loop` avoid variable capture? And is it a reliable general principle that whenever a macro expands (only) into other macros with variables, that variable capture will not be a problem (since the other macros already deal with it)?

Comment: In this case the SBCL LOOP implementation sees that the LOOP limit 3 is a constant and for that it won't introduce a variable in the generated code.

Comment: For complete code expansion in SBCL you can use SB-CLTL2:MACROEXPAND-ALL

Comment: OK, thanks. I see now that if you put in a variable for a range extent, `loop` does introduce an uninterned symbol.